# Why is uploading termed 'uploading' and downloading termed 'downloading'?

Tags: terminology

What is "up" or "down" about it? I mean, geographically it makes no sense. I can upload images, and download images - the former is away from my computer and the later is coming to it but why "up" and "down"?

Comment: I really wish people would just use putting and getting so it was clear what was happening.

Comment: @tchrist: You will then just find people complaining that when they transfer a file from a remote server to their PC, they are *putting* that file on their PC; and when they transfer from their PC to the server, they are *getting* the file to the server.

Comment: @JohnY Only people who haven’t been learnt the right way.

Comment: @tchrist Put and get are already technical terms for types of HTTP requests. Not every upload is a PUT and not every download is a GET.

Comment: @SilverlightFox Actually, I was thinking of FTP.

Comment: Using file transfer protocol for file transfers?  How quaint.

Comment: To make things more confusing, the up/down direction is reversed when one is discussing transferring programs between a PC and a PLC. There, downloading is from PC to PLC, and uploading is from PLC to PC. See [this forum discussion](http://forums.mikeholt.com/showthread.php?t=54102) and [this manual](http://www.plcdev.com/book/export/html/597), for example.

Comment: The larger computers/servers/chips/networks are always "higher" than the smaller ones which are "lower", so UP-to-DOWN goes: {*Internet Servers, Local Servers, PC/Desktop/Laptop, Mobile devices, PLCs*}.  This was established at least as far back as the 70's.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is the same concept as **upstream** and **downstream** in a river.

Heading **upstream** is heading **toward the source** of a river.  Heading **downstream** is heading **away from the source**.

If you consider a computer server to be the source of a river:  **uploading** is sending something up to the server (upstream to the source); **downloading** is pulling something down from the server (downstream from the source).

Alternatively, some people prefer to consider the stream bi-directional because this represents a closer picture to the truth.

In this metaphor, *whoever is serving the file* represents the **upstream** side, and *whoever is receiving the file* represents the **downstream** side.

Hence, when you **download** you are standing downstream *waiting for the file to come down* from the river's source (the server).  And, when you **upload**, you become an *ersatz server* and the actual server now becomes the **downloader**.  So, you are now the **upstream**, and the server is the **downstream**.

Regardless of which way you view things, Up and Down continue to agree directionally.

Comment: Not to mention which you *give things **up*** when they leave your possession, and you might *take **down*** someone's details as part  of the process of *receiving* that information.

Comment: I see your point, however if I upload an image then the source is my local computer, if I download the image then the source is the server. So the source changes, thus uploading and downloading are both away from the source.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Excellent usage of logical thinking, but it really is more the stream metaphor that was used here.

Comment: @JJ Yes, you are correct.  (More so than you realize!)  When you reverse the transaction the *server* is downloading the files you are uploading . . . In this case, you are the upstream and the server is the downstream.  Hence you have uploaded.

Comment: @JJ I've edited it to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: I'd upvote this if there were a reference.

Comment: I like the first part of your explanation, but I don't buy the idea that you become the upstream partner when you upload --it would seem to make more sense to me that you are sending the file "upstream" to the source, i.e. the server.

Comment: @user867 I wish I could find you one.

Comment: @ChrisSunami That is the way I originally explained it.  But, some people are confused.  That's the trouble with metaphors.  Upstream to the server makes perfect sense if you assume that there is a stronger current.  But, JJ has a point, when you reverse the direction, in effect you are now the server.

Comment: I would have upvoted if you hadn't made the edit, but I think you ruined your metaphor.

Comment: @ChrisSunami Give me a moment.  I will make everything clearer.

Comment: @ChrisSunami I have now pandered to all bases.

Comment: I don't buy this unless the metaphor can be applied to the earlier sense of *upload*. I think the *up* there is simply that when you upload items you put them upon each other.

Comment: @JonHanna I don't follow.  Put them upon each other how?

Comment: Putting one item upon another.

Comment: This is a good way of thinking about it. Another way of thinking about it, which makes sense in a more recent sense, is to think of the internet, servers etc as the cloud. You upload into the cloud, you download from the cloud.

Comment: @Tobberoth it's a fine way of looking at it (at least if you're already forced to use the dreadful metaphor of *cloud*) but while a reasonable way to re-imagine the metaphor after the fact, doesn't make sense in terms of the words origin, which somewhat pre-dates that use of *cloud* by decades in the computer-specific sense and over a century generally.

Comment: @JonHanna There is no sense of putting items on top of one another in the computer sense. If anything, quite the opposite. The computer world has used the term file and related terminology. It is a sense of discrete organization into directories or folders. Not some haphazard piling of items upon one another.

Comment: The question is "Why is uploading termed 'uploading'", and "What is "up" or "down" about it?" that the answer doesn't relate to the sense in question doesn't stop it being the answer.

Answer (score 9):

*Uploading* originally meant loading up a cart, trailer, truck, etc. with items. In this sense it is of 19th century origin. As the OED cites:

> 1870   W. Barnes *Select. from Unpubl. Poems* 18   Low-headed horses slowly haul The newly-made hay, uploaded high.
>
> 1976   *Aviation Week & Space Technol*. 22 Mar. 57/1   At present most C-5/C-141 pallets have to be reconfigured prior to uploading the C-130, particularly the two pallet spaces in the wheel-well area.

Like many terms in computing (such as *computer* itself), a term from the physical world was applied to the task of putting data from one machine unto another, especially when the destination was larger or more significant in some way (which was often the case with client-server systems, especially in the 70s or earlier when the term came into use in this sense). Hence uploading files was compared with uploading goods.

*Download* was then the obvious antonym.

Like quite a few metaphors used in computing (again, like *computer* itself), the word is now rare in its original sense, and almost only used in the computing sense.

Comment: Have you got a source for this?  Every dictionary I've consulted says the term originated in 1977 (or 1979), and not a single one makes mention of carts, etc.

Comment: Also, in the 1970s the usage was most used with regard to space program computers, in which case the the up side was actually the smaller computer.  But, up was used because it was literally *up*.  *Down* was used in a similar sense.

Comment: I believe you are confusing the term with [*onloading*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/onload)

Comment: @DavidM: Here's a quick [1870](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=tMwNAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA60&dq=uploading&hl=en&sa=X&ei=IPAOU8uuHOnj4QS594CgAQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=uploading&f=false): "The rate of carriage current about that time was £20 **uploading** from Rockhampton, and £10 from Broadsound to Clermont; while wool and copper as **down-loading** was taken at £13 to £14."

Comment: @DavidM I've added the first and last citation of usage from the OED to my answer.

Comment: So, you believe that the original users of the terms were thinking of antiquated 19th century carting terminology when they coined the terms?  I would find it easier to believe that the terms evolved in a convergent manner.

Comment: @DavidM no, I think the original users where thinking of current 20th century terminology, that originates in the 19th Century. This is hardly rare with computing terms; *computer* is 17th century, *window* is 13th, *mouse* goes back to early Old English.

Comment: @JonHanna I would think that if that were the case, more dictionaries than the OED would still list upload and download with secondary meanings similar to the one you've described.  I just don't see the coiners as appropriating the terms from the teamsters and shippers.

Comment: @DavidM lots of people have moved house and other tasks that involve uploading. Did the dictionaries you consult list it as a separate word entirely?

Comment: I cannot find that sense of it in any dictionary except the OED.

Comment: The word can certainly be found used in such sense, with that found by @Hugo a particularly interesting case as it contrasts it with *download*. Since that is demonstrated, it is the dictionary that omits it that is less useful here, than the dictionary that includes it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say this has to do with how hierarchies are traditionally drawn in IT (and pretty much everywhere) - the root/superior is at the top, the leaves/subordinates are at the bottom. It works the same way when drawing a schematic image of the network. You have the internet (with its servers) on top, then the local network beneath it (rooted at the router), and the client computer (the endpoint) at the very bottom.

This way, **uploading** and **downloading** corresponds to moving data **up** and **down** this diagram.

Comment: +1: Suprisingly, this is the only answer here that captures the salient point: *UP* and *DOWN* had to do with the infrastructure and networking hierarchy charts first seen in the 70's.

Answer (score 0):

In computer programming *stream* is a very common term and describes way of exchanging data: one by one, in a specific order, first in - last out, no swapping (like a queue), and if something went through, there is no way to go back to it, no way to rewind and read it again.

This is the way files are transmitted via HTTP. Parties are connected by a stream, so we call *upstream* where the server is and *downstream* where the user is (the most common direction of transmision).

Hence *upload* - pushing files upstream, *download* - pushing files downstream.

Comment: Parties are not connected by a stream in HTTP. In that context, *stream* refers to the sequence of octets in either direction sent over the *connection*, and it is the *connection* that connects them. *Downstream* and *upstream* don't really work with that sense of *stream*, though they do in some other metaphorical uses.

Comment: HTTP lays on a TCP connection, which is a bidirectional stream of octets. But in most cases most of data goes in a server->client direction

Comment: The use of upload* and *download* in computer communications precedes the common usage of *stream* by quite a lot.

Comment: you are right, my answer is no good

Answer (score 0):

from the OED:
"To transfer (data, etc.) from one computer or device to another (esp. to one that is larger or remote from the user, or is functioning as a server). Cf. download v."

from the American English Dictionary:
"the action or process of transferring data to another computer system."

additionally:
in the days before the web and the internet and social networks and cloud computing and PCs (or Macs) or tablets, phablets and smartphones, a person usually used a terminal connected to a huge server that might be connected to another gargantuan server. so up is a matter of size or cost -- as in upscale. so up is big, down is smaller; up is also higher up in the hierarchy of machines; down is where the servant machines (terminals, printers, modems, routers, etc., are.

does that make sense?

cheers!